# How can I dentify or select cms_blocks that are associated with certain cms_page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, cms-pages

I am trying to pull cms blocks that belong to a certain page. i saw that blocks are stored in cms_block and pages stored in cms_page. I tried to create a query that might help me pull this data.

```
SELECT cms_block.title FROM cms_page INNER JOIN cms_block ON cms_page.page_id = cms_block.block_id;
```

and

```
SELECT cms_page.title FROM cms_page INNER JOIN cms_block ON cms_page.page_id = cms_block.block_id;
```

with both of these queries I do get some results. But I suspect that the results are not accurate because when i try to load cms page and cms block using either page_id or block_id with same id. the pages that comes up are  totally not related.

Example:

`http://domain/index.php/admin/cms_page/edit/page_id/7/` loads unrelated data compared with that following block;

```
http://domain/index.php/admin/cms_block/edit/block_id/7/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, CMS Pages are not related to blocks in any way.

You can show CMS Blocks in pages by calling them in XML or in code

Comment: cool, I'll try to create a custom table thanks